# Does every attribute of a view have to depend on the original table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

I know that SQL view is a virtual table based on the result-set of an SQL statement. So it might depend on a table, copying its columns but it doesn't have to. Its columns can be some computed values. And view doesn't have to simply copy the table's values, it can process them first.

My question is if we can have a view column that isn't simply based on an SQL statement, but it is a declaration of a column to which we can later insert any values we want. For example,

```
CREATE TABLE persons (
    id int8,
    age int8,
    name varchar(255)
);
```

and then we create a view from `persons`:

```
CREATE VIEW persons_view AS
SELECT id, age FROM persons,
code int8;
```

where `code` is a declaration of an independent column of type `int8` that is not updated dynamically when `persons` change. However this code is a syntax error. We could insert anything we want as `code` later,

```
UPDATE VIEW persons_view 
SET code=2094
WHERE id=1;
```

Of course we could not do the same for `id` or `age` because they are linked to the original table `persons`. `code` would be an additional column that contains additional information and is not linked to the original table. My question is general, but I'm focused on PostgreSQL.

Is it possible to create such an additional column in a view not linked to the original table?

Comment: Please add a tag for a specific database product; In most I'm familiar with, views (without extra configuration) have no storage of their own, so no ability to store any additional information. However, it may be that your *specific product* does offer such functionality.

Comment: Also, please prefer to store date of birth rather than age. Storing age, you're guaranteed that at some *unknown* point in the next 366 days it'll become incorrect.

Comment: A view is just a predefined SQL statement, it has no storage capabilities

Comment: There are some contraditions in your own description/understanding of a view, your SQL query is also invalid.

Comment: @Stu, well I just learned what a view is, I wanted to use it in another way as it is designed, according to other comments

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, you said *without extra configuration*. What do you mean?

Comment: Since you've specified Postgres, the specific concept it has is [Materialized Views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, but a materialized view is just a type of view, so it's actually true that views can have additional storage? I'm confused...

Comment: I just read about materialized views in the provided link, but I still don't know how to apply it to my case

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @NickW and @Damien_The_Unbeliever for the comments. I will just paste them here as an answer because I believe they are right.

A view is just a predefined SQL statement, it has no storage capabilities. Views (without extra configuration) have no storage of their own, so no ability to store any additional information.